# Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs to keep the arrangement on a mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm struggling to make Bootstrap 4 nav tabs act in a truly responsive way.

I attached the code and here is a demonstration of what I need.

[image: bootstrap nav-tabs]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container p-4">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">First really long nav</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Second really long nav</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Content of the first tab.</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Content of the second tab.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-nowrap` class in your `nav` class

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container p-4">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs flex-nowrap" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">First really long nav</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Second really long nav</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Content of the first tab.</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Content of the second tab.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.